# Select/Copy the From, To, Date, Attachments header from an Outlook email

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I need to copy some emails into a document (as there doesn't seem to be a handy way to convert a .msg to a .doc or .pdf).

I can copy the message body, but I also want to include the to, from, date and attachments details.

Is there a way to display this?

One option is to print into XPS, - but that loses the line breaks in the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print to a PDF I recommend [CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/writer.asp). It will allow you to print anything to a PDF document. Once you install it, it will show up in your printers. Then just "print" to it and it will generate a PDF for you.

Note: There are many other PDF printers out there, CutePDF is just my favorite to use. If you do not have permissions to install CutePDF check with IT to see if they have a different PDF printer you can use instead.

Comment: That sounds awesome. Unfortunately where I work it's a huge hassle to install new software. I will check what they've got on the catalogue though.

Comment: Ok, there are many different products that print to PDF. They should have something, it's a very common request in my experience.

Comment: Cool thanks - that sounds like the best solution. - If you edit your answer to incldde 'there are also  other PDF printers you can use', I will accept it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.